# How can I share code across static libraries without duplicate symbol errors?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, architecture, linker

I am new to building static libraries and would like to create 2(+) libraries each of which has some unique code and some shared code. My intention is that other projects will link one or more of these static libraries.

```
Util.h/m  <-- Shared
ImplOne.h/m  <-- Unique to 'ImplOne'
ImplTwo.h/m  <-- Unique to 'ImplTwo'
```

I am using XCode and generating the libraries by building `Util.m` and `ImplOne.m` in one case, and `Util.m` and `ImplTwo.m` in the other.

Of course the issue is that I now cannot use these libraries together because they will have duplicate symbols. What is a better architecture for this situation?

Comment: Make it three libraries, sharing the util with implone and impltwo.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thought of that and it would work... is it the only way? Perhaps it is.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest alternative. You can play around with macros to alter names of your functions and variables, but the results are not going to look pretty.

Comment: Fair enough. I definitely can't think of how it could be cleaner. Want to put your comment into an answer? Then I can close this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest alternative would be to make a separate library for the shared `Utils.h/m`. The drawbacks are that your users would need to link `utils` along with `implone` and/or `impltwo`, and that in order to link `impoone` and `impltwo` together both libraries need to be compiled with the same version of `utils`. In return, the source of the libraries would stay nice and clean.

An alternative would be to use macros to alter function and variable names in the `utils` to avoid linker errors. The most important consequence of this is code duplication: both `implone` and `impltwo` would link identical pieces of code under different names. The other one is readability: it would suffer tremendously, because each reference to a function in `utils` would need to be wrapped in a macro. This makes the second approach dirty, so I would definitely recommend making `utils` a separate library.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem to this in a current codebase. My solution is similar to the answer that just came in as I wrote this, but I'll leave it here as a comparison/reference.

I have a common static library project (let's call it libCommonBits.a). I have a second static library which has some UI code in it (let's call that libCommonUI.a), which also depends on libCommonBits.a. My main app needs to use both libraries.

My solution is to not actually link the libCommonBits.a into the libCommonUI.a. It compiles against the header files fine, and just means that my main app links against two static libraries instead of one.

I'm hoping this approach is taken on by more people distributing libraries. It's frustrating when you use a static library that has already linked in common libraries (JSONKit or similar), and you also use that separately in your codebase. In that case, the symbol renaming might be the only solution.